# Parent/child data from Playa 3 loop

Tags: add-on, playa, pixelandtonic

Is there a way to retreive parent/child data from within the Playa 3 loops? I tried using `{parent:title}`, but that just prints that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, using `{reverse_related_entries}{title}{/reverse_related_entries}` does the trick.